# Is the any way to know the process order of a functionality written in Ruby On Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, process

I am studying Ruby On Rails and complete novice at it. I find that it is a bit difficult to trace the process order of a functionality (e.g.: user clicks a button in the form).

I wonder if there is any tool or way to know the process (ie: What method in a controller is called, corresponding model method,....). I would like to trace the order of regarding process and it helps me much in debugging.

Comment: Are you looking for a step-by-step debugging tool? `pry-debugger` gem is very useful.

Comment: The standard rails log should be actually pretty helpful already. There you see which route mathed, which controller was used, and which view was rendered. You can also see all db queries there.

Answer (score 0):

You can use  `byebug` or other debugging tools. Example and other ways of debugging can be found at rails website: http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html

For example if you choose byebug and decide to put it in a controller:

```
class PeopleController < ApplicationController
  def new
    byebug
    @person = Person.new
  end
end
```

When your code reaches `byebug` line of your controller it will pause and wait for your command at your rails server command terminal. You can give various commands at this point, 
for example,

if you type `next` it will move to next line.

if you type `instance_variables` to see all the variable values.

If you type `thread list` for list all threads and their statuses.